# Using groundwater data in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, interpolation, elevation

I have raw data in the form of groundwater levels collected regularly over a couple of years. The values are collected in an excel file together with xy coordinates for the water wells (of which there are between 10 and 20) as well as z ground level values.

My goal is to present the water levels (the important data) in a way that is easy to understand and maybe a bit more interesting than simply showing the position of the wells and keep the values in the attribute table. I want the viewer to understand how the water levels vary within in the area.

But since I'm kind of new to GIS and ArcMap I'm not sure what's a good way to do this. Do you have any suggestions?

What I have done so far is turn the wells into vector points based on the xy values in the excel file. The rest of the values can be viewed in the attribute table.

Since the water wells are located at different heights I guess it's pointless to do an interpolation of the water levels.

Comment: It's a bit odd to ask (as per title) what to do with the data, I mean someone might say, if you don't know what to do with it, archive it...  So better can you explain (edit the question) why you have the data and what do you want to do with it/get out of it, that way somebody might be able to suggest a good way of presenting it to some specified audience.  At the the question is likely to be closed as either too broad, or as primarily opinion based.

Comment: I have edited my question with your criticism in mind. I don't want to go *too* far into the background of the question because I don't feel it's that relevant.

Comment: import the point data into a point feature class (make sure you include the Z field),using Spatial Analyst interpolate the point data to a raster surface, create water table contours from the raster using the Contour tool (3D Analyst or Spatial Analyst)

Answer (score 0):

The description is indeed a bit vague, but as I understand it this is what you can do: since you already have a list of the points, you can easily import this to any GIS software.

For ArcMap: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012745

For Qgis: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html

For visualizing that data you might first execute an interpolation on the depth of the wells. You can then use the DEM and subtract the interpolation to get an interpolation of the actual water table.

Interpolation:

For ArcMap: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/raster-analysis/interpolate-points.htm

For Qgis: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/interpolating_point_data.html

Subtraction:

For ArcMap: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm

For Qgis: https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_calculator.html

Comment: Thank you for a great answer! However, I'm afraid I still don't quite follow you all the way. Where does the DEM come from? And I'm not sure if I have access to the depth of the wells … However, the water levels are measured from the top of the wells and not from the bottom. With that in mind, do I still need the depth of the wells?

Comment: So what data do you have? you have coordinates of the wells and the depth to the water table?